`files list file for package 'linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8' is missing final newline`
Got a fresh installation of Raspberry PI OS Lite on a RPi3.
After apt update & apt upgrade and a reboot, i cant install any new packages/tools.
I receive files list file for package 'linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8' is missing final newline as error message.
pi@testboard:~ $ sudo apt install -y i2c-tools python3-smbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libi2c0 read-edid
Suggested packages:
  libi2c-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  i2c-tools libi2c0 python3-smbus read-edid
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 116 kB of archives.
After this operation, 773 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 libi2c0 arm64 4.3-2+b3 [9,456 B]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 i2c-tools arm64 4.3-2+b3 [78.6 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 python3-smbus arm64 4.3-2+b3 [11.8 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 read-edid arm64 3.0.2-1.1 [16.1 kB]
Fetched 116 kB in 0s (751 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package libi2c0:arm64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

I tried to:

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
sudo apt clean

Nothing helped. The issue still exists when i want to install something.
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"


dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'linux-generic' is missing final newline - A couple of answers suggest checking for /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux, but there may be another solution/explanation...

Thanks to @Greenonline comment, i resolve the issue.
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8.list
apt --reinstall install linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8

The file /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8.list contained some funny chars/was damaged. I think the SD Card has a issue or something went wrong.
Removing and reinstalling the package solved the problem.
